# C compare time_t parameter in func to current time

Tags: c, linux

**Goal:**

I'm trying to write a function that accepts a `time_t` as a parameter and returns a different formatted string by comparing with current time. The data being passed into a function is specifically a st_atim.tv_sec.

**Code:**

```
const char *format_time(time_t then)
{
    static char buf[200];
    struct tm *then_tm;
    struct tm *now_tm;
    time_t now;

    now = time(NULL);
    then_tm = localtime(&then);
    now_tm = localtime(&now);
    
    /* blah blah blah comparisons */
    /* shortened code below */
    strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%c", then_tm);

    return buf;
}
```

**Problem:**

`then_tm` and `now_tm` both have the `tm` form of the parameter `now`.

If I swap these two lines around...

```
then_tm = localtime(&then);
now_tm = localtime(&now);
```

```
now_tm = localtime(&now);
then_tm = localtime(&then);
```

... then they both have the `tm` form of the parameter `then`.

`then_tm` should be different to `now_tm`.

**Misc**:

- I am writing a curses file manager as practice.
- GCC
- Linux

Comment: The `localtime` function has a limitation in that it always returns a pointer to a single, static result buffer.  That limitation shows up when you call `localtime` twice like this, and try to save both pointers as if they're different.  Either switch to `localtime_r`, or change `then_tm` and `then_tm` to `struct tm` (not pointer-to-`struct tm`), and say `then_tm = *localtime(&then)`.  (This is risky, however, since `localtime` can also return NULL.)

Comment: @SteveSummit I think this should be an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(credit to @SteveSummit)

> The localtime function has a limitation in that it always returns  a pointer to a single, static result buffer

I have refactored my code to use `localtime_r` like so:

```
const char *format_time(time_t then)
{
    static char buf[200];
    struct tm then_tm;
    struct tm now_tm;
    time_t now;

    now = time(NULL);
    localtime_r(&then, &then_tm);
    localtime_r(&now, &now_tm);
    
    strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%c", &then_tm);
    
    return buf;
}
```